# Power BI: Extend expiration time of access token getting by Get-PowerBIAccessToken

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I can get Power BI token via Power shell by using this command `Get-PowerBIAccessToken`

Token is valid but expiration time of this token is 1 hour.

I want to extend this token to 1 day but I can't find information how I can do that.

I logged into PowerShell from master account.

I tried to create `New-AzureADPolicy` token with new value of expiration time, but now I cant to assign this policy to the current user(master account). As I understand this policy can be assigned only for a Service principle and I'm not a service principle

Do you have any solution to extend token's lifetime?

Comment: Can you share some details on why you want to extend the token lifetime?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Yes sure: I have 2fa authorization on my account, so I can't login and create token with it in my server side application. So I think that I can create token once with long lifetime

Comment: `Client Credentials Flow` works better for server side applications/daemon.. it makes use of `Application Permissions` though instead of `Delegated Permissions`, if the API you're interested in works with `Application Permissions` then it might be a better route.. Also, AzureAD does provide a preview feature for configurable token lifetimes (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes), but it's about to be replaced by session management capabilities in Azure AD Conditional Access. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running a *secure* unattended service, your best approach would be to use app-only authentication (a.k.a. "service to service") to obtain an an access token to the Power BI service. Your app's access to Power BI will not be dependent on any user's account, it will have it's own service identity.

You can read more about Power BI support for app-only access to the Power BI API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal

With app-only flows, you have two options to authenticate the app:

- With a certificate - this is the more secure, recommended approach
- With a client secret - this is less secure, and carries a higher security risk

The Power BI cmdlets support both modes of app-only authentication. For example, to authenticate using [a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#register-your-certificate-with-azure-ad), it's a simple as:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal `
                              -Tenant "{tenant-id-or-domain}" `
                              -ApplicationId "{client-app-id}" `
                              -CertificateThumbprint "{cert-thumbprint}"
```

Alternatively, using a client secret:

```
$clientSecret = Get-SecretFromSomewhereSafe # Do NOT include the secret in your script!
$cred = [PSCredential]::new("{client-appid}", $clientSecret)
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal `
                              -Tenant "{tenant-id-or-domain}" `
                              -Credential $cred
```

Once you've connected with either approach, then you simply get an access token immediately before you would use it:

```
Get-PowerBIAccessToken
```

If the existing cached access token is still valid, it will be returned. If it has expired, the cmdlet will take care of retrieving a new one.

Comment: This is neat, but doesn't work when your access token expires midway through e.g. an Import refresh.

Comment: Midway through a single API request or cmdlet call? Or something else?

Comment: A single API request (like a long running import)

Comment: Power BI behind the scenes doesn't support refresh tokens which would resolve the issue, I believe it's on their roadmap.